# Date parsing exception when in the Brazilian DST period

Tags: java, timezone, dst

When entering the brazilian DST time period, the clocks are forward 1 hour. In 2014, DST began at 19/10, so the time 19/10/2014 00:00:00 became 19/10/2015 at 01:00:00. The period between "does not exist".

Because of this, when parsing the date "19/10/2014 00:45:00" using the timezone America/Sao_Paulo, it's thrown a parsing exception: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19/10/2014 00:45:00".

```
String date = "19/10/2014 00:59:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setLenient(false);
sdf.setTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
```

America/Sao_Paulo timezone supposedly supports DST changes. What is the expected fix for this problem? I must change manually the jvm timezone when the DST period starts and ends? Currently the "fix" is changing the jvm timezone to GMT-2 when the DST period starts.

Note: This issue originated in an application developed with spring. The example date was throwing exception when it was being converted to a java.util.Calendar from a String. In the example code above, I set lenient to false in order to be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: This is not compilable: `sdf.setTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo");` But else I think it is a good thing if Java rejects an invalid local timestamp in strict mode.

Comment: Yes it's invalid. Was my editings on the code :p I think it's the correct behaviour to reject the missing period too. But what should be a suitable solution for this?

Comment: That's strange. I change the year of the date and it works... 2013, 2015, 2010... The problem is just the 2014... That's very strange =S

Comment: I know what's going on, I don't know how to solve it. 19/10/2014, here in Brazil, was the first day of the Summer Time. Then, between 00:00 and 01:00, from the code, it's like it never exists.

Comment: In 2013, 2015 and 2010 it works because the date when the DST started in Brazil changed. Check there: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/brasilia. The moment of the change isn't the same every year.

Comment: Update, FYI: [Brazil canceled DST observance as of 2019-04](https://time.is/time_zone_news/no_dst_in_brazil_in_2019).

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Calendar` represents an instant in time.  That instant has to exist.  When local time values fall into a spring-forward DST gap, those values have no representation as a real instant in time.  In other words, a properly configured clock in Brazil will never show 00:45:00 on 19/10/2014.  Thus the exception.  See [the DST tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) for a visual representation.

Since you are parsing user input, I recommend parsing the string to a `LocalDateTime` instead of a `Calendar`.  For Java 7, you can get this from [Joda-Time](http://joda.org/joda-time/).  For Java 8, this is built in to the new [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Once you have it as a `LocalDateTime`, then you can decide where to go from there.  If the time is invalid (falling into the gap of the spring-forward transition), or ambiguous (due to the fall-back transition), you can detect these scenarios and decide how to handle them in your application.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use *java.time* to adjust from 00:45 to 01:45 in accounting for the [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) cutover.

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "19/10/2014 00:45:00" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss" )   // Returns a `DateTimeFormatter` object. 
)                                                          // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
.atZone( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Sao_Paulo" )                       // Returns a `ZoneId` object.
)                                                          // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toString()                                                // Returns a `String` object holding text in standard ISO 8601 format extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

> 2014-10-19T01:45-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible date-time classes that are now legacy.

Your input string lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
String input = "19/10/2014 00:45:00";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

A `LocalDateTime` is just a date with time-of-day. So this class cannot represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. To determine a moment, we must place the `LocalDateTime` in the context of a time zone, thereby producing a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Sao_Paulo" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "ldt = " + ldt );
System.out.println( "zdt = " + zdt );
```

When run.

> ldt = 2014-10-19T00:45
>
> zdt = 2014-10-19T01:45-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

We can see that *java.time* made the necessary adjustment. The time-of-day of 00:45 was changed to 01:45.

Be sure to understand the logic used by *java.time* in this adjustment. Study the Javadoc. Only you can decide if such an adjustment is the right thing to do for your business logic.

Answer (score -1):

Is date originated from user input or stored information? Note that setting GMT-3 to JVM is not the same as "America/Sao_Paulo". I don't believe GMT observes daylight saving times. Switching JVM setting back and forth doesn't look like a good solution. If it's just stored information you could update the value 1 hour ahead ou backwards, not sure which is the case here. Setting GMT-3 timezone was the only explanation I see for ending up having an invalid date in America/Sao_Paulo timezone.

Comment: The date is originated from user input. I think GMT-+XX does not support DST, and I think that is the major difference between GMT-3:00 and America/Sao_Paulo. I'm kinda confused right now. America/Sao_Paolo is a valid timezone? :p Just switching the "u" for a "o"? Since the date is originated from user input, I guess I can always calculate the valid hours for each day and display them to the user choose.

Comment: I made a mistake, the correct is Sao_Paulo. I fixed that already. I believe this approach is better.